# non uniform convergence of integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(f_n)\subseteq L(X,\mathbb{X},\mu)$ and $f_n\longrightarrow f$, then I must show that if $\lim_{n}\int \mid f_n-f\mid=0$ then $\int\mid f\mid d\mu =\lim_n \int\mid f_n\mid d\mu$.

i don't know how to use de non uniform convergency on my favor. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inequality $$\left|\int_A |f_n|\mu (dx) -\int_A |f| \mu (dx)\right|\leq \int_A |f_n -f|\mu (dx) $$

Comment: I did this: $\mid\int\mid f_n \mid d\mu - \int\mid f\mid d\mu\mid=\mid\int (\mid f_n\mid -\mid f\mid)\mid \leq\mid\int\mid f_n -f\mid d\mu\mid$ and try to use the convergence here, but I'm not sure if I can limit the last term because the convergence is not uniform, and also, on the firs equality I used a property that can be used only for measurable positive functions, and I don't have that $\mid f\mid$ is positive measurable.